# libgdx - why do all viewports align in center except extend viewport?

Tags: android, libgdx, viewport

I'm using a stage and I have multiple actors within. Whenever I assign any Viewport (Stretch, Fit, Fill) it automatically puts all my actors at the middle of the screen.

I want to use Extend Viewport since it is the most suitable in my case, However, it adds (draws) all the actors starting the left of the screen, and then adds letterbox only to the right.

**How can I align the Extend Viewport to the center of the screen?**

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem. For me it was setting the parameters in the resize function to my box2D dimensions:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {    
    viewport.update(VIRTUAL_WIDTH / 2, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT / 2, true);
}
```

And oddly the [ViewportTest1](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/ViewportTest1.java) worked perfectly in my project. Maybe you can try this test and find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Viewport's `update` method with `centerCamera` set to true.
This worked best for centering horizontally for me, but you can also try using `setScreenX()`.
You'll need to use `setScreenY()`, calculate the offset and `apply()` for vertical centering.